# UK visit visa refused due to unexplained deposits, how to address. complex statement

Tags: visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

I had applied for UK visit visa for purpose of General Medical Council registration, how ever I did not mention some recent deposits in my account.

> The first bank account statement is in your own name (account number
>   ending 9901) from Standard Chartered Bank which shows a closing
>   balance of USD $5,092 (£3,971). I have noted that the account contains
>   an unexplained deposit of USD $700 (£545) on 02/12/2019, the origins
>   of which are unclear. The documents submitted do not show where this
>   money has come from. Therefore, I am not satisfied that the balance
>   indicated by your bank statement is an accurate reflection of your
>   usual financial position and that your personal circumstances are as
>   stated. This undermines the credibility of your application.

**They missed withdrawal from my second statement which was done on same date and converted to USD. The question is how to address it?**

> The second bank account statement is in your own name (account number
>   ending 9901) from Standard Chartered Bank which shows a closing
>   balance of PKR 177,159 (£893). I have noted that the account contains
>   unexplained deposits totalling PKR 247,744 (£1,249) between 07/01/2020
>   and 22/01/2020 the origins of which are unclear. The documents
>   submitted do not show where this money has come from. Therefore, I am
>   not satisfied that the balance indicated by your bank statement is an
>   accurate reflection of your usual financial position and that your
>   personal circumstances are as stated. This undermines the credibility
>   of your application.

**This has two components, first are some bank deposits made by my friends who used my Credit Card to pay exam fee and they returned me the money, these amount to 5 deposits, how can I make acceptable declaration for that?**

**Second is money sent to me from my brother, this was sent to my dormant bank account which I use very less (I had not mentioned this in visa), Now do I need to mention this statement and my brothers statement as proof, how do I make declaration for this?**

Comment: Provide the credit card statement(s) and your own dormant and brother’s bank statements and explain the transactions in your application, as you’ve done here. Based on your question there’s nothing else obvious that you can feasibly do.

Comment: ok do I have to mention my previous refusal in my cover letter?

Comment: You have to disclose it and provide details in the application itself.

Comment: @Traveller reads like an answer to me.

Comment: @Ahub1988 UK visa officers consider financial situation a very much important factor in the application. I had the same situation that I used to transfer from PKR account to my Dollar account, When I applied for UK visa , I clearly described everything in my Cover letter. Please always write a detail cover letter and dont hesitate to make it longer to 2 pages even.

Comment: Was this your first application? Have you traveled to the UK before? What part of the rules was your application refused for?

Comment: Yes first application for UK, haven't traveled to UK before. Refused under paragraphs V4.2 (a) (c) of the Immigration Rules.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the information in your question there’s nothing obvious that you can feasibly do other than:

- provide the credit card statement(s) and your own dormant and brother’s bank statements and
- explain the transactions in your application, as you’ve done here.

You will have to disclose the previous refusal and provide details in the new application itself (UKVI will have the data on file, of course). There’s no particular need to duplicate the disclosure in your covering letter unless you want to provide additional pertinent information that won’t fit in the relevant field in the application.